# How to get the qualifiers from an observed event at runtime

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-6

I want to create a generic observer method, which is able to observe any event implementing a specific interface and, depending on a configuration file parsed at application start, redirect the user to a specific page.

This page is defined by the event class and its qualifiers. It's easy to get the class at runtime, but i don't know where i should place the InjectionPoint to get the event qualifiers, or if there is a better way.

Say, i have this method in an @ApplicationScoped bean (Event is an empty interface which is implemented by all out concrete event classes):

```
public void processEvent(@Observes @Any Event pEvent)
{
    System.out.println(pEvent.getClass());
}
```

Is it possible to get the actual qualifiers for pEvent at this point?

/edit:

It seems like CDI 1.1 has exactly what i need in the form of EventMetadata: http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.1/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/EventMetadata.html

Sadly, WebSphere 8.5 has CDI 1.0 and is lacking said class.

Answer (score 1):

It's a pity that neither search on Google  nor search on StackOverflow of "CDI  Event MetaData" (or other-like search) return a correct result.
Actually the current question is not found neither...
You need to know the exact name which is "EventMetaData" (without space).

I needed to look at the CDI 2.0 workgroup document to figure out this EventMetaData class (which is available since CDI 1.1). An example how to use it:

```
public void onLifeCycleChange(@Observes @Any Customer customer,
        EventMetadata eventMetadata) {        
    Annotation annotation = new AnnotationLiteral<Foo>() {};        
    if (eventMetadata.getQualifiers().contains(annotation)) {
        reset();
    }
}
```

This question need to be upvoted for more visibility (but I can't do it myself because of lack of reputation)